# TypeError: "stack" is read-only

Tags: javascript, class, object, error-handling

I have a custom error object and I'm trying to change the stack inherited.

```
this.stack = (new Error(message)).stack
```

For some reason this error only happens in firefox.

```
TypeError: "stack" is read-only
```

[Here's the source.](https://github.com/reggi/error-suite/blob/master/src/multi-error.js#L27)

Answer (score 4):

You're extending [es6-error](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/es6-error) which defines the `stack` property like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(this, 'stack', {
  enumerable : false,
  value : (new Error(message)).stack,
});
```

[Source](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/es6-error/blob/01da2528a86bd6fbfc7491540449fcdb445ca632/src/index.js)

By default, the `writable` attribute of a defined property [is supposed to be `false`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineproperty). In strict mode, [this will result in an error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode). So it appears that your code is running under strict mode in Firefox.

Comment: Is there a way for me to interact with the `es6-error` class and have a `stack` that is writable?

Comment: @ThomasReggi Not really. Attempting to redefine a property [will result in an error.](https://jsfiddle.net/sydjzb21/1/) You could make a new property under a different name but you can't change the existing property.

Comment: @ThomasReggi You could use `Object.defineProperty(this, 'stack', { ... })` instead of assignment (`this.stack = ...`) to create a property specifically on the prototype child even when the prototype parent has a non-writeable property of the same name. I don't know how/if that works with class mechanics, though.

Comment: @apsillers I tried this and I get another error `can't redefine non-configurable property "stack"`

Comment: @apsillers That won't work in this case because the property is defined through a `super` call. It's just like if the `Object.defineProperty` was in the constructor itself.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that as soon the OP mentioned the other error. Ah, well. -- @ThomasReggi My suggestion assumed that your subclass instance (i.e., prototypal child) did not have its own `stack` property until the call to `setMessage`, but I see now that it *does* have its own `stack` property, set by the super call, and you can't change it.

Comment: Thanks everyone! The owner of the `es6-error` module published an update and made stack writable! YAY!